# CORS, withCredentials and third party cookies

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to do a CORS GET that sends the cookie along with it. I've set all the headers (`access-control-allow-origin`, `access-control-allow-credentials`, `access-control-allow-headers`) in the server and am using `withCredentials: true` and `crossDomain: true` in the jquery ajax request. Everything works when I tell my browser to allow third-party cookies. Is there any way to do this without forcing visitors to allow third party cookies? I've even tried redirecting the user and redirecting back, but CORS will refuse to send the cookie along. :/

I've tried doing the CORS request via ajax, as well as via an iframe.

Comment: what do you mean "allow third-party cookies"? CORS still enforces the cookie's same-origin policy, so it can only send cookies from the server's origin. You can send a cooke from one origin to a different origin.

Comment: I have a page from domain A.com, and i'm trying to do a GET/POST from B.com on A.com's page. Both these domains are trusted. Does that make sense?

Comment: A.com can only read/write cookies from A.com. B.com can only read/write cookies from B.com. withCredentials doesn't let Javascript on A.com read cookies from B.com, it only indicates that requests from A.com to B.com should include B.com's cookies. So even with CORS, the cookie's same-origin policy is still enforced.

Comment: that's the thing, requests going to B.com does not include B.com's cookies if I disallow third party cookies

Comment: In that case it would be useful to see the code you are using to make the request, and a capture of the request and response headers (from the browser's debugger).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it is possible. See my (old but relevant) [blog post](https://blog.zok.pw/web/2015/10/21/3rd-party-cookies-in-practice/) on this.
The only bullet-proof way is to use 1st-party cookies (that is, open window in a top-level window like a separate tab, or redirect current window).

In some cases it is not necessary though. Browsers have slightly different notions of what third-party cookie is, and default behavior is also different. [This post](http://labs.fundbox.com/third-party-cookies-with-ie-at-2am/) has a nice overview on these details. So in some cases you could do tricks to enable (or at least detect) use of cookies on the page.

Other workarounds include putting one server under a subdomain of the other (subdomains are usually not considered 3rd-party), or changing the flow so that the user is authenticated by other means than cookies.

Answer (score 1):

if you set cookie (origin 2 set cookie) you should know third party cookie will be used, but if you only get cookie (only send cookie for origin 2 without setting in response) there is no reason third party cookie play a role.

so i think you set a cookie in origin 2 and because of that force you enable third party cookie.

> Note that cookies set in CORS responses are subject to normal
> third-party cookie policies. In the example above, the page is loaded
> from foo.example but the cookie on line 19 is sent by bar.other, and
> would thus not be saved if the user's browser is configured to reject
> all third-party cookies.
> [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)