# Can I allow 1st-party cookies using CORS in iframe in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cookies

Why my cookies with cross-domain request and `withCredentials=true` no longer sends when "Block third-party cookies" is enabled in Chrome?

environment: `Chrome 80.0.3987.122`, `nodejs server`, 2 domain (`a.com`, `b.com`)

Test case:

1. Set cookie using new rules `test=cookie; SameSite=None; Secure` for domain `a.com`
2. Write `<iframe src="https://b.com" />` and put it to `a.com/index.html`
3. Write `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', 'https://a.com/', true);
   xhr.withCredentials = true;
   xhr.send(null);` and put it to `b.com/index.html`
4. Add CORS to `a.com` like: `access-control-allow-origin: https://b.com` and `access-control-allow-credentials: true`
5. Open `https://a.com` in Chrome

**As a result**: xhr request to `a.com` success sent and got 200, but: When "Block third-party cookies" is **enabled**: cookie `test=cookie` cookie is not present in the request.

Why? This is a **first**-party cookie because domain `a.com` is opened in chrome tab.

Facts:

1. New google cookie design **allows** to make cookie with `SameSite=None; Secure` ([source](https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie))
2. CORS allows to send `site cookies` when `access-control-allow-credentials: true` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials))
3. XMLHttpRequest allows to send cookies with `withCredentials=true` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials))
4. `Request` and `Cookie` for `1rd-site` (not 3rd) while the option is called a `block third-party cookie`

Chromium issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=918322

Comment: Is this 3rd party cookies in your question?

Comment: @DeepKakkar this cookie `test=cookie; SameSite=None; Secure` sets to `a.com` and `a.com` is main site with iframe inside.

Answer (score 0):

> Why? This is a first-party cookie because domain a.com is opened in chrome tab.

It's a third-party cookie because the the request was triggered by `b.com` even though `b.com` is framed by `a.com`.

I suppose you could work around that by using `postMessage` to send a message to `window.parent` (which is `a.com`) and have the page there respond by making the XHR request itself.

Comment: You're wrong. Third-party cookie will be when I will try to save and cookie from `b.com` for `b.com` like with localStorage: `Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.` because `b.com` now cant save any info in user PC about itself. But `test=cookie;` is valid 1st-party cookie (he could not be saved if he were 3rd). I know about `postMessage` but this topic about CORS mechanism. Main idea of "Block third-party cookies" is different and should not have this behavior.

Comment: @MixerOID — You might disagree with what Chrome considers a third-party cookie but you're running into reality. I offered `postMessage` as a work-around.

Comment: ok, you want to say that Google deviated from the XMLHttpRequest specification and does not say about it? Spec: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-withcredentials-attribute

Comment: @MixerOID — The third party cookies user preference would be pretty useless if it didn't reject cookies from third parties even if the first party wanted them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858737/cors-withcredentials-and-third-party-cookies

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=918322 Fount my case

Comment: Which is closed as WontFix because it is the expected behaviour when third-party cookies are blocked by the user.

Comment: Nope, as a result: `Probably, w3c is a better place to discuss`